# Accessing Google Calendar using a public/private calendar link in GData (no hardcoding the passwords)

Tags: ios, security, calendar, gdata, gdata-api

I'm currently creating an app that will access a company's google calendar and display the event information in a table. I would like to be able to access this calendar without hardcoding the credentials using statements such as:

```
[googleCalendarService setUserCredentialsWithUsername:username password:password];
```

I was reading up on Google's API console and how you can create an OAuth 2.0 client ID to access information. Would this be the most secure way to access it and does GData for iOS support this? How would I go about integrating it? Besides that I was also looking into just reading the calendar from a public/private address. This seems to be giving me more than a hassle though as I'm just receiving errors when attempting to use the provided public/private addresses from the calendar with the method: `[googleCalendarService fetchPublicFeedWithURL:calendarURL feedClass:[GDataFeedCalendar class] delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(calendarsTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];`

Comment: I actually thought I did tag it. Either or, it's not a question about the IDE. It's a question about google's API.

Comment: @ErwaySoftware means your question is **not** about XCode, that is why it was removed.